# ActiveMQ Message Forwarding

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have the following problem: 
I have access to the transportConnector of ActiveMQ broker A. Lets say the uri is tcp://123.123.123.123:61616. I need to set up broker B on another ActiveMQ instance in order to forward all messages from broker A to tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 and from tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 to broker A.

If it is possible to do this without changing configuration of broker A? If yes, then please provide me with directions on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answer is incorrect, you can initiate the network connection from Broker B to Broker A. As long as Broker A has not disabled advisory messages, then you can subscribe to topics/queues that originated on Broker A, on Broker B.

Simply define a network connector with duplex="true"

The "access to transportConnector" is the key bit. If you can connect to the broker, you can have it's messages forwarded to another broker.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to forward the messages from the Broker A to Broker B without changing the configuration of the Broker A. 
You will need to define a [networkConnector](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) to forward the messages.